# Passing variable from JSP to another one

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jsp

I want to pass a String from one JSP called list.jsp to another one called details.jsp

I've got a 'button' in list.jsp as it follows:

```
  <a class="more-info-title" href="details.jsp?address=<%=resultSet.getString("address")%>">MORE INFO ></a>
```

Now in details.jsp I want to get the variable called 'address' so I do the following:

```
  String address=request.getParameter("address");
```

Turns out it doesn't seem to work. When I click on the button I get the following:

[image]

Also here's part of my controller:

```
@RequestMapping("details")
public ModelAndView helloDetails() {
    final ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("details");
    return mav;
}


@RequestMapping("list")
public ModelAndView helloList() {
    final ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("list");
    return mav;
}
```

Comment: how is the `details.jsp` url end up?

Comment: Like this if the address is "Crazy Street 1414" localhost:8080/null/hello/details.jsp?address=Crazy%20Street%201414

Comment: what is `null` in the url ? where did you put `request.getParameter("address");` ?

Comment: hmm, it left me wondering is the `list` looked like `localhost:8080/null/hello/list.jsp`? because a not found (404) error appears when the designated route is not mapped to any controller or static resources. if not, probably as benjamin suspected, the `null` part might come from somewhere else that causes the issue... and may i check with you whether this built on [spring](https://spring.io/)? if yes you need to tag this properly.

Comment: @BagusTesa yes list url looks like you said. The problem might be spring related (yes, I'm building on spring).

Comment: @benjaminc I put   `<% String address=request.getParameter("address"); %>` at the beginning of my details.jsp right after the imports.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure from where you are getting the address in the list JSP.
If you are routing your request through controller you need to add the parameter from the request again in the ModelAndView object to access it in the newly rendered JSP file.

```
 <a class="more-info-title" href="details?address=<%=resultSet.getString("address")%>">MORE INFO ></a>
```

For routing your request from the controller you need to change the "href" value as above(It should be same as you have mentioned @RequestMapping in the Controller).

```
@RequestMapping("details")
public ModelAndView helloDetails(HttpServletRequest request) {
    final ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("details");
    mav.addObject("address", getParameter("address"));
    return mav;
}


@RequestMapping("list")
public ModelAndView helloList() {
    final ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("list");
    return mav;
}
```

Comment: I can't compile it since getParameter is undefinded for the controller

Comment: My bad, it was request.getParameter("address"). Thanks for your time, this worked.